# Extend something to somebody

Tags: usage, sequence-of-tenses

We usually say **extend something to somebody** but in the following sentence

[The law created a group called ‘Socially and Educationally Backward Class’ and included Marathas as the sole group under the category, and extended 16% reservation outside the existing quotas **for** Scheduled Castes and Tribes, and other tribes and backward classes.](https://www.thehindu.com/opinion/editorial/boost-for-marathas/article28213627.ece)

**extend something for somebody** is used. Is it correct?

One more sentence in the same passage is

> Thus, it says, an extraordinary situation has been created wherein the State **had** to treat them as a separate category.

When the entire sentence is in  the present tense then why is **had** used here?

In the following sentence

> Further, Marathas have been classified as the only **member** of the newly created ‘SEBC’.

When they have used plural verb then why is member used here? I think it should be members

Comment: Here's another example: *I extended my fishing rod.*

Comment: @JasonBassford I think you did not understand my question

Comment: On the contrary, I did. My example was meant to illustrate that we do *not* always say *extend something for somebody*.

Answer (score 0):

> We usually say extend something to somebody
>
> extended 16% reservation outside the existing quotas for Scheduled Castes and Tribes, and other tribes and backward classes.

"Scheduled Castes and Tribes" is not "somebody". "Scheduled Castes and Tribes" is a variegated diverse complex group. So, you can not simply, easily, and literally give *something* to *somebody*. The word "for" is more apt in this case. If we swapped in "to", the resulting sentence still makes sense but seems sub-optimal.

In any case, there's nothing wrong with "for". Consider "This gift is for Jill." You can use "for" when extending benefits to somebody.

> When the entire sentence is in the present tense then why is had used here?

You can mix tenses in certain cases. Consider: "I am telling you now, in the present tense, that Jesus died (past tense) more than 2000 years ago."

> Further, Marathas have been classified as the only member of the newly created ‘SEBC’.

It may be something like this:

"Germany has been a member of NATO since 1955."
"The Germans have been a member of NATO since 1955."

Answer (score 0):

I do not want to comment on Indian English, which is a variant of English spoken by millions. Nuances of grammar or usage in Indian English may well escape me.

In formal American English, the passage is unclear, partly because the legal structure being discussed is unfamiliar to Americans, but also because the prose is awkward to an American eye. Here is my best guess at translating it into formal American English.

> The law created a legal category, called “Socially and Educationally Backward Class,” that included only Marathas. That category was allocated a reservation of 16% that was in addition to the reservations already allocated to socially disfavored castes and tribes.

The passage may be perfectly good Indian English, but is very hard to interpret reliably by someone skilled in American English, at least someone not familiar with terms of art used in Indian law.